# Ruby spawn a process that outlives the lifetime of the program

Tags: ruby

I have a program, where I am starting a program called [mpv](https://mpv.io/). I want to use the shell to start mpv with a video, and then exit my ruby program. My problem is that currently, the mpv instance is killed the the ruby program ends. How can I fix this?

```
# do some stuff
system 'mpv \"#{video_url}" & disown'
# end of program
```

I have also tried using

```
pid = Process.spawn "mpv \"#{video_url}\""
Process.detach pid
```

The program is that both of these will make the mpv process be killed immediately. If I do not exit, or if I sleep at the end of the program, the video plays until the program ends. How can I make spawning of mpv last longer than my ruby program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use exec(). It will terminate your ruby program and execute the given command

```
exec('mpv \"#{video_url}\"')
```

or you can use spawn too

```
spawn exec "mpv \"#{video_url}\" &"
```

Comment: The mpv command is blocking, meaning the ruby program will not terminate. Nothing happens when I try adding `&` or `& disown` at the end of exec either.

Comment: Try using fork { exec('mpv \"#{video_url}\"') } instead. It should execute the command on another proccess

Comment: It still exits at the same time as the ruby program

Comment: You can also try with spawn(exec('mpv \"#{video_url}\"'))

Comment: This nearly works, I just had to make two tweaks. The first was changing single quotes to double quotes, and the second adding `&` at the end. If you update your answer to `spawn exec "mpv \"#{video_url}\" &"`, I will accept

Comment: _"you can use spawn too"_ – yes, you can use `spawn` and you can use `exec` but you can't mix and match these. `spawn(exec("..."))` doesn't make much sense. First because `exec` terminates the Ruby process and `spawn` is never reached. Second because `exec` would have to _return_ something that is a valid argument to `spawn`, i.e. a string. But `exec` doesn't have a return value. (because it terminates Ruby)

Comment: "&" is a shell built-in. This cannot work in an environment without a Bourne-compatible shell, for example in Windows.